# Global php variables not defined inside functions

Tags: php, global

My php code looks like this:

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode(file_get_contents("data.config"), TRUE)), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) 
{

    if($key == "user")
        $user = $val;
    else if($key == "pass")
        $pass = $val;
    else if($key == "server")
        $server = $val;
    else if($key == "data")
        $data = $val;
}

if(!empty($_GET) && isset($_GET['function'])) call_user_func($_GET['function']);
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['function'])) call_user_func($_POST['function']);

function dbcon()
{
    return new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$data);
}
```

But when I call `dbcon()`, I get undefined variable: user and so forth for the other 3.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please comment stating the reason for the downvote so I know what I did wrong and will try to not repeat it again.

Comment: because they not `global`

Comment: Are you including the file that declares and defines your variables?

Comment: I did try global but no use...

Comment: Try `global $user` inside `dbcon()` function. Also make sure that `$user` is set to some value

Comment: I want to see your `data.config` just for fun... Need it really recursive parsing?

Comment: If someone ask a question, why downvote him because he forgot something in his code? Is stackoverflow not the place to ask questions,  resolve problems and/or correct incorrect code?

Comment: @Danny, yes.  But SO is _also_ an archive of high quality questions/answers maintained for the benefit of future readers.  Down-votes indicate a variety of issues and should never be taken personally.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @Sparky i know, but sometimes ... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `global` keyword for this:

```
function dbcon()
{
    global $server;
    global $user; ...
    return new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$data);
}
```

But you should not to use global variables
Simple always inject all your dependencies

```
function dbcon($server,$user,$pass,$data);
```

for example, or better: `function dbcon($options)`;

Or the best way is the OOP learn and write separate class for incapsulate all of this....

**Some offtop.**
Replace this:

```
if(!empty($_GET) && isset($_GET['function'])) call_user_func($_GET['function']);
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['function'])) call_user_func($_POST['function']);
```

with followed:

```
$allowed_foos = array('allowed_foo1', 'allowed_foo2');
if(
   !empty($_REQUEST) && 
   isset($_REQUEST['function']) && 
   in_array($_REQUEST['function'], $allowed_foos)
) 
  call_user_func($_REQUEST['function']);
```

Comment: Bro u gucci! tnx. My problem was that I used global outside of the function instead of inside.

Comment: also, I skip this: `call_user_func($_GET['function'])`; Remove this immediately... If this is really needed, you should create "whitelist" for be sure that params, you get is params you wait...

Comment: How can I make it only call functions that are defined in functions.php?

Comment: I write "whitelist" example

Comment: But that will require me to repeat the names of all the functions... Only if I could write a function that will make the whitelist for me....?

Comment: You should to understand, that you allow to run any php code without it